# ssrs not see all the information in chart axis

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

why when this is little information this sees ok, i am not sure but i believe this work ok with max 8 or 10 axis-information in this case codigos de producto or product code.

this is not the first report which get this bug.

[image]

but when this is big information[image]
i dont see the others products code,  it show only somes. about 5  or 4 codes,

these are my horizontal option[image]

the answer of @register user works fine

[image]

Comment: IS the Y axis with the same range? 1000,2000,etc? Can you post your chart/code?

Comment: Can you put your vertical asix >> Axis Option >> and set Min, Max, interval and interval type to auto.

Comment: chart code? there is not code only queries that do you need?

Comment: @Hiten004 why vertical? is it not horizontal?

Comment: Sorry i mean horizontal!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your question "how do I get the X-axis to show all product codes regardless of the number of codes?"  If so, then explicitly define the Interval = 1 in the Horizontal Axis Properties -> Axis Options -> Interval section.  This should force it to show each label every time.  You may also want to edit the Horizontal Axis Properties -> Labels and Labels Fonts screens to force rotating the labels, changing the font size, etc., instead of relying on the auto and default options.